# how to drop all indexes of a sqlite table

Tags: sqlite

I have a simple question: How to drop all indexes of a sqlite table?
I have multiple indexes created with random name.

Regards,
Pentium10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware that you can drop ALL indexes in one command - IMO you have to drop each by name. See also: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_dropindex.html Also, check this out for additional info: [Drop all tables command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525512/drop-all-tables-command)

Comment: I need to drop indexes of a table only, not all from the database.

Answer (score 22):

To get all index names in a database

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type == 'index'
```

For a specific table:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type == 'index' AND tbl_name == 'table Name'
```

Then in your language, iterate thought the results and drop them

```
FOR x IN RESULTSET
  SQL = "DROP INDEX " & X
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

DB=your_sqlite.db
TABLE="some_table"

INDEXES="$(echo "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type == 'index' AND tbl_name = '$TABLE;" | sqlite3 $DB)"
for i in $INDEXES; do
  echo "DROP INDEX '$i';" | sqlite3 $DB
done
```

Make sure no other process accesses the database, while you call this script, or if thats not possible add

```
PRAGMA busy_timeout=20000;
```

in each `echo` that you send to the database

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it in **Android** (with the help of [Robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16861797/1617737) and [this SQLite page](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_dropindex.html):

```
/*
 * Drop all indexes.
 */
try {
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type == 'index'", null);
    int numIndexes = (cursor == null) ? 0 : cursor.getCount();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Num indexes to drop: " + numIndexes);
    if (numIndexes > 0) {
        String[] indexNames = new String[numIndexes];
        int i = 0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            indexNames[i++] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
        }

        for (i = 0; i < indexNames.length; i++) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Dropping index: " + indexNames[i] + "...");
            db.execSQL("DROP INDEX " + indexNames[i]);
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "...index dropped!");
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error dropping index", e);
}
```