# How to execute a simple SQL script line in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have the following command to drop all tables, to be performed in onUpgrade:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i2) {
    // Drop all tables...
    String query = "select 'drop table ' || name || ';' from sqlite_master " +
                       "where type = 'table';";
    db.rawQuery(query, null);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

However it doesn't seem to do anything. All my old tables are still there. How do I execute this query properly?

Comment: Seems like it would be much simpler to do it the normal way... `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + classname.tablename);` once for each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [source of this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525512/drop-all-tables-command) says:

> The output of this is a script that will drop the tables for you.

But you are never looking at its output.

You have to read the output of this query, and execute every returned string.