# iOS: How to suppress all tables, index in my sqlite programmatically, except one specific table?

Tags: ios, sql, swift, sqlite, fmdb

I try to delete all the elements in my sqlite to reconstruct it with an .sql file. For this I found that [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/548297/3581620):

```
PRAGMA writable_schema = 1;
delete from sqlite_master where type in ('table', 'index', 'trigger');
PRAGMA writable_schema = 0;
```

I use the [FMDB](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/tree/master/AWSCore/FMDB) to execute SQL commands for info.

I precise that I don't want to empty the tables, I want to completely reconstruct my sqlite, so I need to delete all the elements in the sqlites like tables, indexes.
EDIT:
I am trying to do a sort of loop, but sqlite is not SQL, so I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just delete the database file? Then you start off with a fresh, empty database?

Comment: @Corion I could do that, but I am anticipating the fact that my customer will ask me to keep some informations in only one table. I am updating the title of the ticket